# Cannot find GLFW library on macOS (Bazel)

Tags: c++, bazel, glfw

I'm working on a simple OpenGL application using C++, Bazel, and GLFW. When I attempt to build the rule for my app, I get the following error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lglfw3
```

My environment:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7
- Apple clang version 12.0.0

Here is my `BUILD` rule for the target:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-glfw",
    srcs = ["hello-glfw.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@glfw//:glfw",
    ],
)
```

I'm trying to build GLFW as an external dependency. My `WORKSPACE` file has this:

```
http_archive(
    name = "glfw",
    build_file = "@//extern:glfw.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "glfw-3.3.2",
    urls = ["https://github.com/glfw/glfw/archive/3.3.2.zip"],
)
```

The contents of my `glfw.BUILD` file is:

```
DARWIN_DEFINES = [
    "_GLFW_COCOA",
    "_GLFW_NSGL",
    "_GLFW_NO_DLOAD_WINMM",
    "_GLFW_USE_OPENGL",
]

DARWIN_HDRS = [
    "src/cocoa_joystick.h",
    "src/cocoa_platform.h",
    "src/glx_context.h",
    "src/nsgl_context.h",
    "src/null_joystick.h",
    "src/null_platform.h",
    "src/posix_thread.h",
    "src/wl_platform.h",
]


DARWIN_SRCS = [
    "src/cocoa_time.c",
    "src/posix_thread.c",
]

DARWIN_LINKOPTS = [
    "-lglfw3",
    "-framework OpenGL",
    "-framework Cocoa",
    "-framework IOKit",
    "-framework CoreFoundation"
]


cc_library(
    name = "glfw_src",
    hdrs = [
        "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
        "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
        "src/egl_context.h",
        "src/internal.h",
        "src/osmesa_context.h",
        "src/mappings.h",
        "src/xkb_unicode.h",
    ] + select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": WIN32_HDRS,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": LINUX_HDRS,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": DARWIN_HDRS,
    }),
    srcs = [
        "src/context.c",
        "src/egl_context.c",
        "src/init.c",
        "src/input.c",
        "src/osmesa_context.c",
        "src/monitor.c",
        "src/vulkan.c",
        "src/window.c",
        "src/xkb_unicode.c",
    ] + select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": WIN32_SRCS,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": LINUX_SRCS,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": DARWIN_SRCS,
    }),
    defines = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": WIN32_DEFINES,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": LINUX_DEFINES,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": DARWIN_DEFINES,
    }),
)

cc_library(
    name = "glfw",
    hdrs = [
        "include/GLFW/glfw3.h",
        "include/GLFW/glfw3native.h",
    ],
    linkopts = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": WIN32_LINKOPTS,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": LINUX_LINKOPTS,
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": DARWIN_LINKOPTS,
    }),
    deps = [":glfw_src"],
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue on Mac. The Bazel rules I found for GLFW didn't work for me on Mac OS so I decided to rewrite them. After running into several linking errors I managed to get it fully working and I reported my findings [here](https://caandewiel.github.io/vulkan/Vulkan-Engine-Part-2/#bazel-rules-for-glfw). I suppose you already managed to solve your problem by now, but I hope it's useful for anyone else running into this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, to compile against 3.3.7 or more, you need to add the `defines = ["GLFW_INVALID_CODEPOINT"]` to the glfw.BUILD

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to remove `-lglfw3` from the block of code:

```py
DARWIN_LINKOPTS = [
    "-lglfw3",
    "-framework OpenGL",
    "-framework Cocoa",
    "-framework IOKit",
    "-framework CoreFoundation"
]
```

so it reads:

```
DARWIN_LINKOPTS = [
    "-framework OpenGL",
    "-framework Cocoa",
    "-framework IOKit",
    "-framework CoreFoundation"
]
```

The glfw3 link request is probably a cut and paste error from instructions for building against glfw that is prebuilt.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Now I'm seeing a new error: 

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__glfwLoadLocalVulkanLoaderNS", referenced from:
      __glfwInitVulkan in libglfw_src.a(vulkan_5e8a7b500a6a55500f41cfc8f7e8adf4.o) [etc. etc.]

Comment: You're probably missing a source file from glfw in the list of sources.

Comment: Did anybody figure out what this error is about? I'm having the same one with version 3.3.8 of glfw and the contents of the file as above.